# Error in installing/ running serialport in node.js

Tags: node.js

Have been trying to installing/ running 'serialport' on Node.js but it fails.

First I tried installing the current version 0.7.3 and it fails with the following errors

```
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/anand/node/node_modules/serialport/serialport_native/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.237s)
cp: cannot stat `build/Release/serialport_native.node': No such file or directory
```

Next I tried installing version 0.6.7. It installs correctly but when I try to run the examples I get the following error

Error: Unable to load shared library /home/anand/node/node_modules/serialport/serialport_native.node

I have checked that the library exists and has read/write/execute permissions.

I have also checked with different versions of Node including 0.6.4, 0.6.10